# clock_gettime suddenly not working anymore today, what could be the issue?

Tags: c

My code suddenly not working anymore today, what could be the issue?
Here is the part of the code.

```
struct timespec tp;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tp);
int32_t tnow = tp.tv_sec * 1000 + tp.tv_nsec / 1000000;

if (tnow - decoder->last_dumped >= 300) {
    decoder->last_dumped = tnow;
    // it was working before
    ...
}
```

Comment: You are more likely to receive help if you are more specific. Does it not compile? Does it compile but does not link? Does it compile and link but crashes? Does it compile, link and run but does not do what you want?

Comment: Another good idea is to go through the effort and present a minimal working program with a main function. For 2 reasons: (1) You may find your error yourself when preparing the program because it actually runs, and the problem is in parts that you don't even show; (2) because it's really little effort for a reader to copy and paste the code somewhere and run it while it takes a multiple to write even a minimal main() oneself.

Comment: Since you have a lot of experience with script languages: One common error in C are dangling pointers. Make sure the objects and subobjects of `decoder` are properly initialized and have not been deleted or gone out of scope in the meantime. Such errors also sometimes show and sometimes don't, depending on which memory gets re-used in which way.

Comment: Your arithmetic has integer overflow.  A 32-bit integer can't hold seconds * 1000.

Comment: @stark, you're right. that was the case. You may post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tv_sec is a signed integer holding seconds, so 1000 * tv_sec will overflow an int32_t.  Use int64_t.

Overflow will occur after (1 << 31) milliseconds, which is about 24.8 days.

Comment: Thank you. It was actually ok for 23 days, but it overflow at some points during day 24, because of CLOCK_MONOTONIC seems to be start counting from system start (uptime).

Comment: Added calculation